How to prevent the JVM timezone from being taken into account when loading "timestamp without time zone" into LocalDateTime
When loading "timestamp without time zone" into LocalDateTime, the JVM timezone is taken into account, which leads to shifted timestamps.
database column:
some_timestamp timestamp without time zone

JPA entity:
@Column(name = "some_timestamp ", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime someTimestamp;

If the data is loaded via e.g. pgAdmin you get the actual timestamp. However, if the data is loaded via the pgjdbc driver, the timestamp is modified according to the JVM / system timezone.
Example:
system timezone: UTC+01:00 Amsterdam, Berlin, ...
database value: '2018-03-25 02:00:00'
pgAdmin select result: '2018-03-25 02:00:00'
pgjdbc driver result: '2018-03-25 03:00:00'

I have read that there was a bug fix in the pgjdbc driver for the other direction (for the conversion from LocalDateTime to "timestamp without time zone").  See https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/2850 with the actual fix in 2852.
However, my issue is the direction "timestamp without time zone" to LocalDateTime.
Does anyone know how to prevent the jdbc driver from taking the JVM / system timezone into account?
